# Question related to previous state implementation using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how the react's website suggests the implementation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

My question is, can we use **useState** instead of **useRef**?

If yes, will it be any different from the **useRef** implementation?

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(count);
  return <h1>Now: {count}, before: {prevCount}</h1>;
}

function usePrevious(value) {
  // can we use "useState" instead of "useRef" here?
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: No you cannot use useState , if the component remounts then It will lose the previous value so you need to store it in useRef , which saves the value even if the component remounts

Comment: Sure, you could probably use the `useState` hook instead, it'll just trigger more rerenders than is necessary and maybe *not* what you want.

Comment: @DrewReese, could you please explain why useState will trigger more rerenders?

Comment: It's a large part of React component rendering, i.e. components rerender when state or props update. I was referring to each render cycle when you "cache" a current value (to be the previous value on the next render) you update a state, which will trigger an additional render cycle ***before*** you get to the "real" next render cycle when all your state has "synchronized". This is why using the React ref is preferred, it doesn't trigger rerenders since it's just a mutable bin for any values.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, eg

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [prevCount, setPrevCount] = useState();
  const setCountAndPrev = (newCount) => {
    setCount(newCount);
    setPrevCount(count);
  };
```

and then proceed to use `setCountAndPrev` (extract the whole thing into another hook if you want) - but it's a tiny bit convoluted.

If both state are not set at once, it could be inefficient since state setting results in re-renders, which should be avoided when not necessary. It's usually not a problem, but it might be considered more elegant.